# How to show only category axes values in AMCharts for AMStock chart

Tags: amcharts, amstock

I am working with amchart to build a strip chart using AMstock (rotated).

Is there a way to display only category axes values on a panel? [see sample screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieQ90.png).

I have 2 charts. Left should show only category axes values. the right shows the strip chart.

Right now I am stuck at creating the chart options to show only category axes values (double values).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by removing the stock graphs entry for my panels.

```
...
'panels': [
        {
          'showCategoryAxis': true,
          'title': 'Value',
          'percentHeight': 100,
          'lineThickness': 2,
          'autoMargins': true,
          'autoMarginOffset': 0,
          // as you can see, the stockGraphs is commented out.
          // 'stockGraphs': [{
          // }],
        }
      ],
...
```

hopefully this helps somebody.